# Scheduling a job with google cloud scheduler

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

i have a cloud function that works perfectly with this code and me testing it in google cloud.

code to run cloud function

```
import requests

url = 'https://europe-central2-spiritual-grin-390008.cloudfunctions.net/function-4'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}  


response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json={})

if response.status_code == 200:
    print('Function executed successfully.')
    print('Response:', response.text)
else:
    print('Function execution failed. Status code:', response.status_code, response.text)
```

on cloud i have created a service account that has editor, cloud function invoker, and cloud scheduler runner permissions.
while creating a scheduler i have the same region, putting that servoce account, on cloud function too im using same service account. in headers of cloud scheduler im giving same headers that i have in my code and then cloud adds second header of User-Agent: Google-Cloud-Scheduler

but when i run the scheduler it gives me an error of INVALID ARGUMENT, can you tell me what might be wrong and what can i do to fix it.

i tested that same service account with basic cloud function and scheduler and it worked so im assuming its not a service accounts problem

this is the full error from cloud

```
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished", "jobName":"projects/spiritual-grin-390008/locations/europe-central2/jobs/near_earth_asteroid_data", "status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT", "targetType":"HTTP", "url":"https://europe-central2-spiritual-grin-390008.cloudfunctions.net/function-4"}
```

Comment: Can you provide the full error message?

Comment: PS: When you provide  the message put it into question please and don't use the comment section for this.

Answer (score 1):

There are several factors that may cause `INVALID_ARGUMENT` error:

1. Your client might be misconfigured, sending out a wrong log name or other arguments. You may check your URL config:

   ```
   https://europe-central2-spiritual-grin-390008.cloudfunctions.net/function-4
   ```

   as opposed to:

   ```
   https://www.europe-central2-spiritual-grin-390008.cloudfunctions.net/function-4
   ```
2. Check your service account if it has the correct permissions. You may follow the instructions through this link on [using authentication with HTTP targets](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/http-target-auth).

If the aforementioned steps still didn't work, you may reach out to [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) or you could [file this as a bug](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).