# Cloud Scheduler is failing to call the API intermittently with - INVALID_ARGUMENT

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler

There is already a question - [Cloud Scheduler suddenly giving "INVALID_ARGUMENT" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77084234/cloud-scheduler-suddenly-giving-invalid-argument-error)

but this is different than my issue, as I think the above one is more of API issue.

cloudscheduler's profile photo
cloudscheduler
11:26 AM (5 minutes ago)
to cloudscheduler
Hi,

I have a cloud scheduler which is calling a GET API. The API is deployed on Cloud Run Service.
I have three schedulers which run at 3 AM, 11 AM and 12 Noon.
Usually, schedulers 11 and 12 are failing with following error .

@type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished"
jobName: "{jobName}"
status: "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
targetType: "HTTP"
url: "{Working-URL}"

We have a retrigger logic, so when it fails it will try one more time to execute the API. and next time it's always successful.

May I know the reason, why it is failing?

--------------Logs--------------------

```
{
  "insertId": "ftx03cfhpuodj",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "jobName": "projects/{projectName}/locations/{location}/jobs/{name}",
    "url": "{working_url}",
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished",
    "targetType": "HTTP"
  },
  "httpRequest": {
    "status": 400
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_scheduler_job",
    "labels": {
      "job_id": "{name}",
      "location": "europe-west1",
      "project_id": "{id}"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2023-10-19T09:01:20.669503061Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/{id}/logs/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2023-10-19T09:01:20.669503061Z"
}
```

Comment: Can you share more error logs? Make sure you have given required permissions and double check your values in the URL as mentioned in these threads: [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76559959/18265570) & [thread2.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62216424/18265570)

Comment: Thanks Roopa , Logs are added in the original question. However, the permissions are also perfect. because retriggers work perfectly, and this is not a frequent issue, this is intermittent and this week it failed almost alternate days, Especially batches in the afternoon. Do you think maybe it's because of the peak hours in Europe?

Comment: That could be the one of the reason. It also happens when API is unreachable. It is beeter to implement the [retries](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.jobs#retryconfig) with exponential backoff in the Cloud Scheduler jobs. Or you can redeploy the job if it is possible for you

Comment: Yup! We have added retry logic, that the saviors now! But I will try to redeploy the jobs. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Can you update me once you deployed jobs?

Comment: Sure, As of now I cannot update as it is running in production, but after internal approvals and deployment, I will update you.

Comment: Hi @pritampanhale, Have you got any updates to share with us?

Comment: I tried re-deployment with one of the jobs and it failed once only after that. So I am planning to get help from the Google Support Team now.

Comment: You have chosen correct path for your issue. Support team is best suitable for your issue to be resolved as they can inspect your project and identify the root cause.